# FTA Catia R24 Associative Front view (VBA)

Tags: vba, geometry, catia

does anyone know how to create Associative Front View in FTA using VBA. I have short macro to create Front View based on the geometry from 3D but this view is isolated and I must manually change it to Associative. 
What I would like to have is Associative View created by macro. It is first step to perform macro for power copy.

Bellow my code.

```
Sub CATMain()

Dim partDocument1 As PartDocument
Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim part1 As PART
Set part1 = partDocument1.PART

'--------------------------------------------------
'Create Annotation Set

Dim annotationSet1 As AnnotationSet
Set annotationSet1 = part1.AnnotationSets.Add("ISO")

'Debug.Print annotationSet1.Name

Dim theViewFactory As TPSViewFactory
Set theViewFactory = annotationSet1.TPSViewFactory

'--------------------------------------------------
'Create reference plane from selection

Dim ViewPlane As Reference


Set Selection = partDocument1.Selection
Selection.Clear
Selection.Search ("name='Plane.6',all") 'Search plane by name

Set ViewPlane = Selection.Item(1).Value 'Set plane from selection
Selection.Clear

'--------------------------------------------------
'Create Front View

Dim theView As TPSView

Set theView = theViewFactory.CreateView(ViewPlane, 0)
theView.Name = "FrontView"

'--------------------------------------------------
'Create dimension



part1.Update

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that ? Anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I my knowlodge on Catia API go, it is not possible to associate a `view` using the API.

Also, using Win32 to perform clicks on buttons/comboboxes from handles will not work because to associate the view to a plane/surface you will need to perform a click on the desired location using the Catia User Interface.

the `TPSView` object on the API is probably one of the worse ones ever exposed, it doesn't have any property. Also, the `TPSViewFactory` and `TPSViews` don't have any usefull method to manager views.

So, the short answer is **no, you can't do that**.

Comment: The annotation API has been significantly expanded in recent releases of CATIA V5 (2017,2018,2019).  I think this question is now solvable. Please look at the "Whats New" page in the Automation Documentation for your release.