# How to make 'principal views' in CATIA VBA?

Tags: vba, annotations, catia

[image: 1]

I'm trying to make a MACRO using FTA, but I don't know how to make 'Principal Views' like the picture.

If you know anyone, please let me know.

I don't know what to do.

If you know anyone, help me.

Comment: You may have a look on the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48689280/17172829 Which shows an example and also the limitations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.